# Grails 2.0 Documentation - how to print it out?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Is there a PDF for the Grails 2.0 documentation, or another mechansim to readily print it out?  There was a PDF for version 1.3.7.  I need to get a printout to read away from my computer.   Thanks.

Comment: When we switched to the new look the PDF generation broke and we haven't gotten it working yet, so the PDF isn't published currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till the PDF generation is fixed, you may use some pdf writers and a get a readable copy- I use http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/. Once installed you can open them html docs(single page) and print to it.

Comment: Jayan, thanks for the reference.  I downloaded the tool, and added an html file to it (the Table of Contents), and it immediately sent it to the printer (it didn't look great, at least the TOC).   Can one first save it as a PDF before printing in order to look at what is produced?  Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure it went to "PDFWriter" printer, not to your real printer?

Comment: It printed directly out on my HP8500 printer -- I couldn't even set it to do 2 pages, etc.  I added the file, and my printer started (undesirable).  I want to save it to a PDF file first.

Comment: You know, you made me realize I could print each chapter at a time right from the documentation web-site.  Did your PDF version come out any better than what you can do, printing a chapter at a time from the 2.0 documentation web-site URL?  Thanks.

Comment: I can send you what i have got (1.3MB)

Comment: Thanks Jayan, I ended up copying each chapter into Word, which actually worked well as all the various shading boxes (that can take up quite a bit of ink) weren't transferred.  Thanks a lot for your help.  Looks like there are more changes to the docs coming, e.g. per my question / posting on Bean Fields and the author's answer to that.